# not able to connect mongodb with dialogflow

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, dialogflow-es, ngrok

Not able to connect mongodb with dialog flow using flask ngrok. I have installed flask ngrok too. The code is not giving the output URL which will be used in dialog flow.
File

```
"C:\Users\91871\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 85, in parse_userinfo
    raise InvalidURI(
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Username and password must be escaped according to RFC 3986, use urllib.parse.quote_plus
```

This is the error command section is showing

I used the flask ngrok code to connect mongodb with dialog flow. But the URL is not coming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.